Split the array inside the json into multiple rows via JOLT
I want to split the array inside the JSON, into multiple rows via JOLT. Here number of values inside the array can be varied.
Input JSON:
[
  {
    "stationname": "station green",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "Date",
        "value": [
          "2024-06-16T19:02:16.970647Z",
          "2024-06-23T15:12:20.450647Z"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": [
          0.453,
          6.453
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": [
          27,
          56
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": [
          7.0261,
          3.5463
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Output JSON:

[
  {
    "stationname": "station green",
    "Date": "2024-06-16T19:02:16",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 0.453
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 27
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 7.0261
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "stationname": "station green",
    "Date": "2024-06-17T19:32:13",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 6.453
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 56
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 3.5463
      }
    ]
  }
]

And if there is any reading without below format then I want to eliminate them with out dividing into multiple lines.
e.g.:
[ 
  {// here no array values
    "stationname": "workstation syn"
  }
]

[
  {//here, no station name
    "Date": "2024-32-16T19:02:16",
    "data": [
      {
        "key": "X2-P1",
        "value": 3.465
      },
      {
        "key": "X1-P1",
        "value": 22
      },
      {
        "key": "weight",
        "value": 4.4312
      }
    ]
  }
]

Can someone please help on this.
Thank you.

There's no Date attribute in the input, how can we bring the result containing that attribute.

Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, I modified the Input JSON with Date details. However, the shared JOLT is not giving the expected output when I added the Date into Input JSON. Could you please have a look. Thank You.

You can use the following spec :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "value": {
              "*": {
                "@4,stationname": "[&1].stationname",//bring value from 4 levels upper part while renaming attributes as "stationname"
                "@2,key": "[&1].&4[&3].key",//bring value from 2 levels upper part while renaming attributes as "key"
                "@": "[&1].&4[&3].value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//only pick one component from the arrays, in which their values repeat, 
   //other than the "data"
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "data": "MANY"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

